# Fast way to get the label of an item x (in DATA) from a list of labels

Tags: python, list

I have a list DATA of n lists, and another list LABELS of n elements corresponding to the labels of the elements in DATA. What is the fastest way to get the label of some element x from DATA ? `def getLabel(x): ...`

A faster way than just doing: `LABELS[ DATA.index(x) ]`

```
DATA = [ [2,5,8], [2,4,3], [5,5,7], [9,8,4] ]
LABELS = [ "AAA", "BBB", "AAA", "CCC" ]

print getLabel( [5,5,7] ); # will prints "AAA"
```

Comment: Depends on how does `DATA` and `LABELS` look like, post some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Maybe consider using another data structure? Or you can't change that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a dict here, with the item from `DATA` as key and corresponding item from `LABELS` as value.

Dicts provide `O(1)` lookup, while searching in lists is an O(N) operation.

```
>>> DATA = [ [2,5,8], [2,4,3], [5,5,7], [9,8,4] ]
>>> LABELS = [ "AAA", "BBB", "AAA", "CCC" ]
>>> get_labels = {tuple(x):y for x,y in zip(DATA,LABELS)} 
>>> get_labels[5,5,7]
'AAA'
>>> get_labels[9,8,4]
'CCC'
```

Comment: and is this faster than LABELS[ DATA.index(x) ] ?

Comment: @shn yes, list.index is an `O(N)` operation while dicts take just `O(1)`.

Comment: It depends on how often you query the labels. If you do that many times, constructing the dict is worth it. If you do it once, your method is better.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary it is not rather get_labels[ [5,5,7] ], more generally: get_labels[ x ] ?

Comment: @shn we can't use lists as keys in a dictionary, so I converted them to tuples. `get_labels[5,5,7]` is actually equivalent to `get_labels[(5,5,7)]`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary ok so for a list x I shoud use get_labels[tuple(x)] ?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I use a version of Python that doesn't have dict comprehensions, so how can I replace this with something supported by my python ?

Comment: Well, I just replaced {k:v for ... in ...} with dict((k, v) for ... in ...)

Comment: @shn use `dict` : `dict((tuple(x),y) for x,y in zip(DATA,LABELS))`